# ReportViewer crashes because of Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.CachedFont GetFont

Tags: winforms, exception, crash, reportviewer

I have a simple WinForms app with ReportViewer control. Most of time it works okay but sometimes displays unrecoverable red cross mark in ReportViewer window or crashes when I scroll through report. I can't figure any factors that cause this behavior but it appears completely random. I hooked an exception catcher and that's what I've got:

Exception.GetType().Name: NullReferenceException

Exception.Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Exception.TargetSite Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.CachedFont GetFont(Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.RichText.ITextRunProps, Byte, Boolean)

Has anyone happen to encounter this problem? Any ways to work this around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it.

The crashes were caused by inline translation software ABBYY Linvgo, which reads words under mouse cursor and displays translation in a tooltip. Looks like it attempted to mess with ReportViewer's memory space or something which caused access violation and subsequent crash.

After I closed this soft the stability of ReportViewer improved drastically.

So you may consider closing any sassy soft if you experience similar problems.